# Amazon EC2 - last command error

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I just got an Amazon EC2 micro instance with Ubuntu 12.04.
The problem is that the `last` command isn't working ...

The error message is :

```
last: /var/log/wtmp: No such file or directory
Perhaps this file was removed by the operator to prevent logging last info.
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You most likely cleaned up your system logs in the `/var/log/` folder a bit too carefully.
This is not a big deal to solve.

**Step 1: Recreate the file using the following command**

```
sudo touch /var/log/wtmp
```

**Step 2: Set proper permissions**

```
sudo chown root:utmp /var/log/wtmp
sudo chmod 0664 /var/log/wtmp
```

**Late edit:**

Question in the comments:

> I'm pretty sure I didn't delete that particular one, can it be sign of an intrusion

The file is a log file used by the linux command [last](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?last) which

> displays a list of all users logged  in  (and
>          out)  since  that  file  was  created

Sure - If I would be the intruder and I want to remove any signs of my visit I would probably remove my login from this log file, but most likely I would not delete the whole file as this would be a sign of intrusion. If I don't care and just want to wipe my trace I might just destroy the whole machine instead.

More likely reason for the missing reason is described in the book [Hardening Linux by James Turnbull](http://books.google.de/books?id=PyqjvNNltqYC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=/var/log/wtmp+gone&source=bl&ots=XDnF7wUz9S&sig=1Iva1Xb0lbAFPKzqoelOnzmPlPA&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ByMQUa7BJs75sgacooG4DA&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q=%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fwtmp%20gone&f=false) when talking about `last` and `lastb`

> To start collecting the data required to populate the output of these commands, you need to create a couple of files to hold the data. **Some distributions automatically create these files, but others require them to be created manually.**

I am not a forensic expert, so I could not tell you how to detect an intrusion and I can't tell for sure you've not be the target of a hack, but personally I believe the described reason might be more realistic.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i didn't delete that particular one. can it be the sign of an intrusion. where to check?

Comment: thought about your question, added some more info to my answer above

Answer (score 3):

You might want to include the btmp as well.

```
touch /var/log/wtmp
chmod 0664 /var/log/wtmp
chown root:utmp /var/log/wtmp

touch /var/log/btmp
chmod 0664 /var/log/btmp
chown root:utmp /var/log/btmp
```